# How to use variable static list when multi user access

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-3, static

this variable works fine if used by one user, but when used by two or more users then the "static" variable will be read by the next user, the first user instance when filling the gridview there are 5 rows of data and I try to access through other browser when entering the page, gridview on the second user already filled 5 rows of data in input by the first user. then how the solution to this problem? please see my code and give me an solutions. thanks.

```
static List<ServicesModels> _gridPackageDetail = new List<ServicesModels>();

private void AddListAction(string alfa, string beta)
{
    ServicesModels data = new ServicesModels()
    {
          id_service_detail = Guid.NewGuid(), 
          scope_name = alfa, 
          detail_name= beta
    };
    _gridPackageDetail.Add(data);
}

public ActionResult GridPackageDetail()
{
    ViewBag.DataListPackage = _gridPackageDetail.OrderBy(a => a.scope_name).ToList();
    return PartialView();
}
```

my code in mvc3 controller.

Comment: Why are you using a static which is shared? Remove the static

Comment: @Wheels73, my sample code is not complete, that's is a summary. because i'm really need to use variable static list. i hope you know what i need. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working fine, because this is what intended by "static", to have  the same data for multi users. In your case you need to create a list or dictionary or multi-dimensional array (any data structure you are comfortABLE with) and save the data per use in it, and then retrieve the data when needed based on the user id.

```
    static List<ServicesModels> _gridPackageDetail = new List<ServicesModels>();

private void AddListAction(string alfa, string beta)
{
    ServicesModels data = new ServicesModels()
    {
          id_service_detail = Guid.NewGuid(), 
          scope_name = alfa, 
          detail_name= beta,
         user_id = getTheID()// Get the id of the user

    };
    _gridPackageDetail.Add(data);
}

public ActionResult GridPackageDetail()
{
    ViewBag.DataListPackage = _gridPackageDetail.OrderBy(a => a.scope_name && user_id ==getTheID()).ToList();
    return PartialView();
}
```

replace getTheID() by your way of getting the id of the user.

This is used if you want to keep the data of all users. else you should remove the static keyword.

Comment: sorry?please translate

Comment: sorry, im forget to write in english. can you help provide the code you mean? =)